# How is it possible that neither if nor else branch gets executed here?

Tags: 6, database

I'm developing one of my first drupal modules and stuck here:

```
$maxexp = db_result(db_query("SELECT max(expiration) FROM {uc_roles_expirations} WHERE UID=%d and rid=%d", $uid_befizeto, 4));
dpm('DB query finished');
dpm('me = '.$maxexp);

if($maxexp) {
   dpm('True branch');
 } else {
   dpm('False branch');
 }
```

This is a snippet from `mymodule_nodeapi`'s case 'insert'. My problem is that I do not understand why do I see the following messages after saving a node:

```
DB query finished
me = 
Node blah saved successfully
```

I simply do not understand if there is no error, how it is possible that I cannot see `True branch` or `False branch` among the messages..

Comment: examined `dpm(is_null($maxexp))` and the result is 1. but when I tried to replace the condition of the `if` statement with `if(is_null($maxexp))` still the same happened: neither true nor false branch got executed.

Answer (score 1):

It was a character encoding problem in the source file. I changed the encoding in my favorite  text editor, and the code started working.